# Horror Ghost Movie; Water dripping from basement knob

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Well I've been trying to get the name of this movie for years. It aired on TV in Canada at least 5 years ago.

Here goes:

I think the movie may or may not have "lakehouse" in the title.

The movie starts out that a nice (maybe blonde) woman probably 30 years old is moving into the house her (Grandfather? or father?) built for her. She is moving in with her boy friend.

As they are walking up to the house, she looks at one of the top floor windows and she sees her (grandfather or father, I'll refer to him as father from now on) in the window. (This is a ghost). Alarmed, she tells her boyfriend that she saw someone in the house. He goes in and searches and finds nothing. Then they go inside.

The main part of the film was that there was this round police officer that was pretending to work on the case that many people died in the area, when in fact he was the scum who hung multiple people then threw their bodies in the lake nearby.

In the film, there is a door to the basement that has a glass doorknob, and in many scenes it is dripping water because of the ghosts of people whose bodies are in the lake. Whenever she goes into the basement to do laundry, she sees flashbacks of the girl being hung in the basement. And often she would get locked inside the basement as well.

I believe throughout the movie when she got locked in the basement, she would end up getting hung by the ghosts or something until she snapped out of it.

I think in the last scene when she figures out it was the police officer who killed everyone, the fat guy tries hanging her the same way etc.

In the end when they put the police officer in jail, all the women who got hung visit her again and smile, and then the LAST scene is her looking up at the house, seeing her father in the window again, this time with a smile on his face.

*This movie was awesome and scary for me as a kid. I hope I get to see it again!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [In Her Mother's Footsteps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844008/combined) (AKA Deadly Inheritance) from 2006:

> Soon after Kate moves into the house she inherits from her father, she begins to see strange images of young women being murdered. At first it appears as if she's losing her mind, but Kate soon discovers that her visions may be hereditary. As this young mom begins to piece together the mystery behind her new haunted home, she realizes that not everything is as it seems.

Now, I say 'sounds' because frankly, all I remember was that Emma Caulfield was in it, but according to the web, it all fits: A blonde woman moving with her husband to her father's house by the lake starts to see women's ghosts, and in the end it was a cop who tried to cover his tracks. Here's the trailer, where the glass doorknob with dripping water makes an appearance around 1:18:

Comment: WOW THANKS SO MUCH! HEHE You sure know how to search for things I've tried searching at least 10 times and never got lucky :)

Time 2 watch this again :)

Comment: Actually, I saw this film (or most of it) once and something triggered the memory. The web helped with details though, 'cause I had almost none. :) Glad you found it.

Comment: Let me know if you have any computer questions that can't be answered on here so that I can return the favour :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Cabin by the Lake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199389/) (2000)?

> Stanley (Judd Nelson) is a reclusive screenwriter who lives by a beautiful 
>   and large lake. His hobby is kidnapping teenage girls, imprisoning
>   them in a soundproof room with a two-way mirror, then taking them out
>   to the lake on his boat, attaching their feet to a concrete block and
>   pushing them overboard (he asks them how they feel knowing they are
>   about to die). He particularly likes to reach into the water, grab
>   them by their hair and pull them up again so he can study their faces
>   more carefully, before dropping them again permanantly.
>
> Stanley has at least five or six of these bodies floating in the lake,
>   ranging in decomp status from skeleton to perfect flesh. Each is
>   dressed in a different outfit. Stanley likes to scuba out to his
>   "garden" every day and clean any detritus accumulating around their
>   bodies, and to make sure their costumes stay in place as they rot.
>
> Stanley is doing this because he is "researching" for his latest
>   script; called The Cabin on the Lake, it is about a man who kidnaps
>   girls and drowns them in a lake. He has already sold this script
>   through an agent, and a director is going to make it shortly.
>
> One girl, Mallory (Hedy Burress) manages to escape from drowning and
>   is rescued by handsome sherriff Boone (Michael Weatherley from NCIS).
>   She is unable to identify her kidnapper, however she creates a sketch
>   with an artist. Boone comments how similar to his good friend Stan the
>   sketch looks.

Comment: Eh, not so sure about this one now. Doesn't really have the supernatural ghosty elements.

Comment: Sounds interesting but, yeah it wasn't this one. Thanks though! :)